# Getting Information from Req.User() into Req.params() in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

After people log into my Express app, I'd like to redirect them to a url that reads:

```
www.mysite.com/:user
```

What I'm having trouble with is that my `req.params` object is coming up as an empty object literal when people get re-directed after logging in.

Ideally what I'd like to do is to somehow take the information stored in `req.user` and pass some of that information into the URL.

So basically I'd like to get from here:

```
router.post('/login',
passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect:'/', failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true}));
```

To here:

```
router.get('/:user', function(req, res) {
    //stuff
}
```

After logging in the `req.user` object reads like this:

```
{
  username: joesmith@mail.com,
  name: Joe Smith,
  password:  dkei348#$kDL^583L,
  formulas: []
}
```

And the code I'm attempting to use is as follows:

```
router.get('/:user', function(req, res) {
var user = req.user.name;
req.params = {
  "user": user
}
```

But this doesn't work because initially `req.user.name` is undefined if someone isn't already logged in, so I can't get past the console error.

Apparently I don't understand how `req.params` is generated in enough detail to get around this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Usually, after login, you would store the user name in a session and you would access it via `req.session.user.name`.  `req.params` comes from pieces of the URL where you would usually not put the user name (like there's no username in stackoverflow URLs - it's in the session).  You can put the username in the URL (like Facebook does), but the URL is not secure so you can't rely on it being correct in the URL.  That's why it is usually trusted only from the session which comes from an encrypted cookie which is not easy to forge.

Comment: It looks like your passport login redirects to `/` so it should be no surprise that there's no username in the URL.  Your redirect is just going to `/`.  Your username should be in the passport session accessed via `req.session`, not in the URL.  If it's not there, then your login code should put the user name into the session so it will be in `req.session` on all future requests from this browser (until the session expires).

Comment: @jfriend00 -- thank you.  Would the information stored in `req.session` then be used to build the URL that can then be accessed via `req.params` on the subsequent redirect?

Comment: You could, but the URL is not the right place to put info that you want to be authenticated and secure.  There is usually no reason to access the username from `req.params` because it's already in `req.session` (if you do your session auth right) so it seems you're trying to solve a problem you don't need to solve  Plus, the URL is not a secure place to put the user name since anyone can then type whatever URL they want and make believe they are some username.

Comment: It appears you are down a rate hole trying to make `req.params` work for you when that is probably not the right solution to your problem.   This happens all the time on stack overflow.  People come here asking about their attempted solution to a problem without describing the actual problem.  What often turns out is they are attempting the wrong solution.  If they would just back up and describe the original, root problem they're trying to solve rather than asking about their guess at a solution, then we can help you find the best solution much better.

Comment: Please back up and describe what you're actually trying to do after login.  What do you want that page to show and do?  Why could you not just put the user name in the session at login and then access the username from the session on all future requests?

Comment: You are right about the superiority of `req.session` vs. `req.user` so I will use that to build the URL.  Personally, I find it's best to make SO questions as specific as possible, which usually means digging into the nuts and bolts of your proposed solutions vs. hypothesizing about best approaches.  Point taken about finding the best solution though, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have username in parameters you shoud redirect to `'/' + req.user.name);` because '/' doesn't have any params. That's why it is undefined. (additionaly you shoud check if parameter is defined and handle the error, so instead of console error you get error 404 or get to next, proper routing path).

[Passport Documentation](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate) privides examples of doiung it:

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/' + req.username);
  });
```

or more complex custom callback :

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/' + user.name);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

But I think it is not a good practice and safer would be to redirect to the proper page/content by req.user value without putting it to URL, for example setting req.auth. and then using `next();` instead of `res.redirect('/' + user.name);` to get to the next middleware. There username would be taken from `req.auth.username`, not from `/:username`.

How does the structure of your routing looks? You shoud make sure `router.get('/:user' ..` is not before `router.get('/login'..`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are wanting to access whatever `/:user` value is. e.g. `www.mysite.com/stretch0`. Therefore you would access it like `var user = req.params.user;`

Comment: Thank you @Stretch0.  I think the problem is that `req.params` doesn't contain anything on the redirect, and more problematically, I'm not sure how to pass the information contained within `req.user` into the URL because it hasn't been initiated yet when it gets redirected.

Comment: You could pass it as a query string in the URL and then access it via `req.query.user`

Comment: I don't think either of these suggestions are actually the right solution because the OP has already authenticated with passport and thus there is a server-side session.  That 's where user info belongs because that's where it is secure and reliable.  Putting it in the URL is not secure and can be spoofed by anyone.  This, the OP should be using `req.session` to store the username, not `req.params` or `req.query`.

Comment: Didn't realise it was already authenticated and was secure information. If you don't want to store it in some sort of DB then you could use req.locals

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a custom handler, instead of letting Passport do all the redirecting:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
      req.flash('error', 'Unable to authenticate user');
      return res.redirect('/login');
    }
    if (! user) {
      return res.redirect('/login');
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        req.flash('error', 'Unable to log in user');
        return res.redirect('/login');
      }
      return res.redirect('/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

This does mean that each logged-in user gets their "personal" URL, because you're redirecting to `/USERNAME`. I'm not sure from your question if that's actually your intention.